# Why whenever I click on a link within my site, any logged in user gets logged out?

Tags: python, django

I have built a hackernews type clone with login system, upvotes etc.

I just have one problem at the moment. Whenever I click a link that redirects me to somewhere else on the site (i.e. localhost/ to localhost/science) the logged in user gets logged out.

Here are some of the key views associted with the problem I think:

```
def index(request, category_id=1):
    stories = top_stories(top=30)
    category = Category.objects.get(id = category_id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        liked_stories = request.user.liked_stories.filter(id__in = [story.id for story in stories])
    else: 
        liked_stories = []
    return render(request, 'stories/index.html', {
        'stories': stories,
        'user': request.user,
        'liked_stories': liked_stories,
        'category': category,
        })

@login_required(login_url = "/login/")
def story(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            story = form.save(commit = False)
            story.moderator = request.user
            story.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = StoryForm()
    return render(request, 'stories/story.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def vote(request):
    story = get_object_or_404(Story, pk = request.POST.get('story'))
    story.points += 1
    story.save()
    user = request.user
    user.liked_stories.add(story)
    user.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Is there a 'next' parameter I can include somewhere that will keep each user logged in as they jump from link to link?

If you need any other parts of the code let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use cookies?

Comment: I'm quite new! I'll read up on it now :)

Comment: @skyline75489 i've done some research, but i'm a little bit confused with how to implemen